# Search column one to column two in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a sheet which has 3 columns.

In column one, I have 317 values and in other two 8000.

Now I have to match column one with column two and column three if either of them have that value I have to print YES In 4th column otherwise NO.

Example:

- Column one has value: 'Big' in A2 cell
- Column two has value : 'Big' in B9 cell,
- Column three has value : 'Big' in B10 cell

then the it should print YES

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=FALSE, ISNA(MATCH(A2,C:C,0))=FALSE), "YES", "NO")
```

MATCH(A2,B:B,0) is trying to locate the position of A2 cell in column B. If it cannot be found in column B, it will give #N/A. So

```
ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=FALSE
```

is checking whether A2 can be found in column B

```
OR(ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=FALSE, ISNA(MATCH(A2,C:C,0))=FALSE)
```

is checking whether A2 exist in column B or column C.

Answer (score 0):

Briefer formula that returns TRUE or FALSE:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,C:C,0)))
```

Formatted:

```
=AND(
    ISNUMBER(
        MATCH(A2,B:B,0)
    ),
    ISNUMBER(
        MATCH(A2,C:C,0)
    )
)
```

The key here is using `0` as last argument to `MATCH`, meaning that the values in the lookup range can be in any order (see [MATCH docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60112&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US))